# dangerouslysetinnerhtml nextJS tag <p>

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem executing `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in nextJS. I want to remove the `<p>` tag, but when it is reloaded it doesn't even appear on the screen.
this is my code

[image]

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 7):

You can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
The `return()` function should be:

```
return (
    <div className={styles.article} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }} />
);
```

I do recommend using [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) to sanitize your HTML before inserting it in the DOM via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.